# Angular Webpack:\\ folder not displayed in chrome dev tools

Tags: angular, google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-production

I have upgraded my app from angular 8 to angular 12, webpack:\ folder was displayed so I could search the sourcemap in devtools but when I upgraded to angular 12, it never displayed, I have tried many things to make it happen but nothing, I have also disable the `production: false` in the `environment.ts` but doesn't work. Also tried `sourceMap: true` in `angular.json` but didn't work. I am desperate now.

[dev-tools image that doesn't display webpack:\\ folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSLfk.png)